# When drawing a polygon in QGIS, finding a point defined by two known distances

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, distance, polygon-creation, tools

I'm looking for some tool or process that runs just like a tool present in Arcmap called 'Distance Distance'.

For example, to draw a irregular polygon defining the first four points, I would like to find the last point using two defined distances. In the case of the 'Distance Distance' tool I can define two distances and at the intersection of the rays end point is defined.

[image]

References about this tool: [some official description](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/editing/create-a-point-or-vertex-at-the-intersection-of-two-distances.htm), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTQFs8uMG5w)

Comment: Which tool do you exactly mean https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-distance-tools.htm ?

Comment: I mean the drawing tool which is an option when drawing polygons in ArcMap. You can check the links I posted above.

Comment: See https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=advanced#the-advanced-digitizing-panel

Comment: (Added a picture) @Alrl I tried to use Advanced Digitizing with Construction Mode on, but I couldn't determine distances from two different points. I keep exploring it...